# php sort multidimensional array: bool(true) instead of an sorted array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array $aFacetConfig and I like to sort after the value for each parent element like "TOPIC" and "GENRE"

$aFacetConfig contains

```
 ["TOPIC"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["edit_type"]=>
    string(10) "predefined"
    ["values"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "astronomy"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "law"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "music"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "chronicles"
    }
  }
  ["GENRE"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["edit_type"]=>
    string(10) "predefined"
    ["values"]=>
    array(40) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "antiphonarium"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "benedictionale"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "biblia"
      [3]=>
      string(2) "at"
    }
  }
```

And now I'm trying to sort the array values:

```
$aSortedFacets = usort($aFacetConfig[$oPropertyCategory->name], function($a, $b) {
    $a['values'] <=> $b['values']; 
});
```

var_dump($aSortedFacets) just prints "1"

How to get the values sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorted values are inside `$aFacetConfig[$oPropertyCategory->name]`. The [documentation](http://$aFacetConfig[$oPropertyCategory-%3Ename]) explain that the output is only a boolean and the array is pass by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

If you want to declare an other variable this should works :

```
$aSortedFacets = $aFacetConfig[$oPropertyCategory->name];
usort($aSortedFacets, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['values'] <=> $b['values']; 
});
var_dump($aSortedFacets);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can see the documentation :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

usort take reference of the array, so he juste change the original var and don't create a copy.

```
usort($aFacetConfig[$oPropertyCategory->name], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['values'] <=> $b['values']; 
});
var_dump($aFacetConfig);
```